# PHP template and external CSS

Tags: php, css, model-view-controller

So I have this PHP website that I am working on that using templates. Any page is divided into three parts: header, content and footer. Each part is represented by a `.php` file.

Header:

```
<html>
<head><link_to_some_css /></head>
<body>
<div id="menuBar">
    xxx
</div>
```

Content:

```
<?php include("header.php") ?>
    <div id="someHTMLContent">xxx</div>
    <!-- 
        How do I link an external CSS stylesheet from within here?
    -->
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
```

Footer:

```
</body></html>
```

The `<link>` tag should resides within the `<head>`, but being within `content.php` I have no access to the head of the html.

Sorry if this has been asked, but I am a little new to implementing a framework-less PHP project in an MVC architecture (hence trying to separate CSS JavaScript PHP files for a better structure)

Comment: Look at an existing MVC framework (CodeIgniter and Yii are very easy to learn) to see how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something included in the header then make it a global variable before including.

```
$header = 'Add something to the head tag';
include('header.php');
```

In the header.php:

```
<head>
<?php
if (isset($header)) {
    echo $header;
}
?>
<!-- Add global headers -->
</head>
```

You could add a more robust solution by defining functions to create CSS tags given a link and then add them into the global $header string. These would need to be included from a `core.php` file included before the header include.

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing, I am not sure if such implementation will be criticized as "dirty" but it works and is so far easily manageable. It would nevertheless be interesting to know about any other way of getting around this tho.

Comment: Wordpress works with hooks to `wp_head`, which is eventually called in header.php, which is included in every file that needs it. If you want to change something in the header, you add your custom function to a hook such as wp_head and then alter global variables there. However, even in wp they make use of global vars like $wp_query etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - no way.

The way it should be done is, that there is an object, which represents all stylesheets, which is initialized upon page creation, then you add your stylesheet, and only then display the page. It should look something like this:

Controller:

```
$this->view->script="viewSomePage.php";
$this->view->stylesheets->add('AddSomeStylesheet.css');
$this->view->render();
```

On the inside, the `render()` function would then take the stylesheets, and pass them on to a view.

View:

```
foreach($this->stylesheets as $stylesheet){
//do some outputing;
}
```

Doing this however requires, that each view is an instance of some sort of a view class. Or has some sort of an array passed down to it in an array. The choice is your's.

This comes from the MVC idea itself, that a view should do nothing more, than display the content that is given to it. Therefore, it should not think, which stylesheet to load, or which template/layout to use. If a particular template/layout already has some stylesheets - fine, but additional ones should be defined in a controller and then passed on to the view.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**
As I sat thinking, I though of a way you might achieve this. And with a might I mean, that I've not tested it, and I do not know if it would work as expected.

You could try creating a simple javascript, that upon page load would take all `<link>` tags and put them in the header.

This is however, a *very* hackish way to do this, and should not be used unless you are desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css_main.php file which store the CSS links.

Examples are...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(THE PATH OF CSS FILE)" type="text/css" />
```

after that, just need to require "css_main.php" on your content .php file

Comment: but that would make the link tag outside of the head tag

Answer (score -2):

You either have the link in the header or inside the content. If you have it in the header it'll load whenever you include the header. Otherwise just put the link inside the content.

Comment: Isn't this, strictly speaking, non W3C compliant? (refering to having the link tag outside of the head tag, although yes it works on some browsers)

Comment: as @Gapton mentions, this is not a standards compliant way to do things. This would result in a webpage that wouldn't validate. In most circumstances, this is not permissable.

Comment: Oh, well...you're both right. It's just a quick solution. It should work on most browsers tho...

Comment: Plus, validation is just a tool. If something doesn't validate but works in all browsers who cares about validation anyway...